# TeX capacity exceeded and parsing errors using decoration on chapter name with tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

My first htlatex issue of 2014 and on the first day also :)

I added this line

`\chapter*{\centering \begin{normalsize}my chapter title\end{normalsize}}`

which works fine with pdflatex, but htlatex gives

```
 ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

When I removed the `\centering`, htlatex gave this error

```
(./foo2.aux) [1] [2] [1] [2] [3] [1] [2]
! Argument of \im:g has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12 ...begin{normalsize}Abstract\end{normalsize}}
```

So, I am not really sure what is the problem. I basically wanted to make an Abstract like page in a book style, and found the above [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737326/best-method-of-including-an-abstract-in-a-latex-book) which works really well with pdflatex, but for some reason htlatex having a problem parsing these commands inside the `\chapter` entry. It seems that it does not like Latex command inside `\chapter{....}` arguments. May be need to protect them? fragile issues? But pdflatex handles them just fine?

Is there a workaround this so I can simply have a title in middle of a page with htlatex?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{htlatex issue 010114}
\author{me}
\maketitle 

\chapter*{\centering \begin{normalsize}my chapter title\end{normalsize}} %crash
%\chapter*{\begin{normalsize}Abstract\end{normalsize}} %parse error
%\chapter*{Abstract}  %only this work
\noindent 
\lipsum[75]
\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{one}
  \section{one}
    \lipsum[75]

\end{document}
```

command to compile:

```
>htlatex foo2.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

.....
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./foo2.aux) [1] [2] [1] [2] [3] [1] [2]
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\centering ->\let \\
                    \@centercr \rightskip \@flushglue \leftskip \@flushglue ...
l.10 ...rmalsize}my chapter title\end{normalsize}}
                                                   %crash
Output written on foo2.dvi (7 pages, 13108 bytes).
Transcript written on foo2.log.
```

some text from the log file showing where the problem:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
--- file foo2.css ---
 [1

] [2

] [1] [2

] [3]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <14.4> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 8.
 [1] [2]
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\centering ->\let \\
                    \@centercr \rightskip \@flushglue \leftskip \@flushglue ...
l.10 ...rmalsize}my chapter title\end{normalsize}}
                                                   %crash
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
```

Using TexLive 2013 on Linux mint.

To get the title centered, this works for htlatex:

```
\begin{center}
  \chapter*{Abstract}  %only this work
\end{center}
```

So I can do what I want using the above solution. But will leave this question here since it shows a problem.

Comment: I'd use a redefinition for `\chapter*` (that is `\@schapter`) so you don't feed `htlatex` the offending tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206754/2891), you cannot put anything as parameter of sectioning commands, as it will be processed in order to make the `TOC`. so while it works in normal LaTeX, it doesn't work with tex4ht. So from conceptual point of view your workaround is in much better than your initial try.
I think that instead of misusing `\chapter` command it would be better to use other means to solve your problem, which is `abstract` printing. What about new environment, which will solve also the need to put `noindent` and `clearpage` into document body?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\abstracttitle{Abstract}
\newenvironment{abstract}{\begin{center}\abstracttitle\end{center}\par\noindent}{\clearpage}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{htlatex issue 010114}
\author{me}
\maketitle 

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[75]
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{one}
  \section{one}
    \lipsum[75]

\end{document}
```

I defined new environment, `abstract`, heading text is saved in macro `\abstracttitle` so it can be redefined if needed. This solution works out of the box with `tex4ht`:

[image]