# Multipage chapter heading seems to be incompatible with htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex, latex2html

I want each chapter to start with an image and I want the text on the subsequent page. So, I defined my replacement for `\chapter` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\MyChapter}[3]{%
    % #1 = image
    % #2 = title
    % #3 = author
    \chapter*{%
        \includegraphics[
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.9\textheight,
            keepaspectratio
            ]{#1}%
        %% How do I insert a page break here compatible with htlatex???
        \pagebreak% TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]
        %\clearpage%  <----  Incomplete \iffalse 
        #2  \normalfont\newline by  \newline#3%
    }%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2 -- #3}
}%
```

Using either a `\pagebreak` or a `\clearpage` works just fine with `pdflatex`. But with `htlatex TeX-SE.tex xhtml` I run into problems.

1. Using a `pagebreak` yields:

   > TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
   >   \sch:ttl ->\includegraphics 
   >                           [ width=\linewidth , height=0.9\textheight , kee...
   >   l.85 ...le-image-a}{My 1st Story}{1st Author Name}
2. Using a `\clearpage` yields:

   > Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line ...

So, how do I put a page break there that is compatible with `htlatex`?

### Possibly Related Question:

- [TeX capacity exceeded and parsing errors using decoration on chapter name with tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152052/tex-capacity-exceeded-and-parsing-errors-using-decoration-on-chapter-name-with-t)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\MyChapter}[3]{%
    % #1 = image
    % #2 = title
    % #3 = author
    \chapter*{%
        \includegraphics[
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.9\textheight,
            keepaspectratio
            ]{#1}%
        %% How do I insert a page break here compatible with htlatex???
        \pagebreak% TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]
        %\clearpage%  <----  Incomplete \iffalse 
        #2  \normalfont\newline by  \newline#3%
    }%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2 -- #3}
}%

\AfterEndPreamble{%
    \setcounter{page}{1}%
    \pagenumbering{roman}%
    %\pagestyle{plain}%
    \tableofcontents%
    \cleardoublepage%
    \pagenumbering{arabic}%
    %\pagestyle{fancy}%
}%


\begin{document}
\MyChapter{example-image-a}{My 1st Story}{1st Author Name}
\lipsum[1-5]
\MyChapter{example-image-a}{My 2nd Story}{2nd Author Name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\MyChapter{example-image-a}{My 3nd Story}{3nd Author Name}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tex4ht` is quite sensitive on things which are written to `toc` (and because it uses own configurable mechanism for controlling which sectioning commands should be printed in `toc`, even starred commands are saved), so you need to be careful in what you use. easy solution is to use normal chapter with optional parameter:

```
\newcommand{\MyChapter}[3]{%
    % #1 = image
    % #2 = title
    % #3 = author
    \chapter[#2 -- #3]{%
        \includegraphics[
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.9\textheight,
            keepaspectratio
            ]{#1}%
        %% How do I insert a page break here compatible with htlatex???
        %\pagebreak% TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]
        \clearpage%  <----  Incomplete \iffalse 
        #2  \normalfont\newline by  \newline#3%
    }%
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2 -- #3}
    \par
}%
```

generated

```xml
 <h2 class="chapterHead"><span class="titlemark">Chapter&#x00A0;1</span><br /><a 
 id="x1-20001"></a><img 
src="sample0x.png" alt="PIC" class="graphics" width="345.00964pt" height="258.75723pt"  /><!--tex4ht:graphics  
name="sample0x.png" src="example-image-a.eps"  
-->    

   My 1st Story <br 
class="newline" />by <br 
class="newline" />1st Author Name</h2> 
<p class="noindent">Lorem ipsum...
```

But, as you don't want chapter heading and I would also make things more configurable, so you could style particular parts of heading differently. move definition of `\MyChapter` to a `.sty` file, `mychapter.sty` for example:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}


\newcommand{\MyChapter}[3]{%
    % #1 = image
    % #2 = title
    % #3 = author
    \chapter*{%
        \includegraphics[
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.9\textheight,
            keepaspectratio
            ]{#1}%
        %% How do I insert a page break here compatible with htlatex???
        %\pagebreak% TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]
        \clearpage%  <----  Incomplete \iffalse 
                #2  \normalfont\newline by  \newline#3%
    }%
    \par
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2 -- #3}
}%
```

and now you can make configuration file for this package, `mychapter.4ht`:

```
\renewcommand\MyChapter[3]{%
\a:MyChapter%
\includegraphics{#1}
\b:MyChapter%
\chapter[#2 -- #3]{#2}
\c:MyChapter%
#3%
\d:MyChapter%
\par%
}

\NewConfigure{MyChapter}{4}
\Configure{MyChapter}{}{}{\HCode{<div class="chap-author">}by\Tg<span class="author-name">}{\Tg</span>\Tg</div>}

\Css{.chap-author{font-weight:bold}}
\Css{.author-name{display:block;}}
```

you need to redefine `\MyChapter` command to insert configurable hooks, which would be configurable with `\Configure` command later. These hooks are introduced with `\NewConfigure{MyChapter}{4}` and are named `\a:MyChapter` etc. You can now configure html tags inserted between arguments, in this example we use only third and fourth hooks to insert some styling for author names.

Updated example:

```xml
    <!--l. 22--><p class="indent" >   <img 
src="sample0x.png" alt="PIC" class="graphics" width="321.2pt" height="240.9pt"  /><!--tex4ht:graphics  
name="sample0x.png" src="example-image-a.eps"  
-->

</p>
   <h2 class="likechapterHead"><a 
 id="x1-2000"></a>My 1st Story</h2> <div class="chap-author">by<span class="author-name">1st Author Name</span></div>
<a 
 id="Q1-1-3"></a>
<!--l. 23--><p class="noindent" >Lorem ipsum
```

[image]